# UINavigationBar turns white and won't close when using navigationItem.searchController in iOS 13

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, ios13, uisearchcontroller

I am having trouble using `navigationItem.searchController` in iOS 13.
The search bar of the search controller is initially closed, but it won't collapse back after I scroll the table view.
It 'bounces' back when I try to hide the bar.

Also, the navigation bar turns white after the search bar appears.
(The navigation bar has a custom tint color; see the attached screenshots.)
Note that this wasn't the case in iOS < 13.

Is this a bug in iOS 13?
If it is, is there a work around to keep the tint color of the navigation bar and make the search bar hide when the table view is scrolled upwards?

The search bar seems to hide when the table view is populated with cells to fill the screen.

The following is the code for my `ViewController`, which is embedded in a `UINavigationController`:

```swift
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
  }
}
```

Screenshots:

[image: iOS 13.2]
[image: iOS 12.2]

**EDIT**:
I managed to 'fix' the new behavior using the new `UINavigationBarAppearance` API, but I still cannot get the original translucent look of the navigation bar and making it collapse.

`UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true` doesn't seem to work along with the new API, so I just adjusted the color to match the translucent version using a color picker.

Also, there does not seem to be a way to collapse the search bar properly.

```swift
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?)
    -> Bool
  {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
      let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
      appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
      appearance.backgroundColor = .redAdjusted  // adjusted to match the translucent version
      appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
      appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]

      UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
      UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    } else {
      UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
      UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .red
      UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: “ make the search bar hide when the table view is scrolled upwards? The search bar seems to hide when the table view is populated with cells to fill the screen.” Unclear what you’re expecting to happen. If you’re doing the search you’re not going to hide the search bar; that would make no sense.

Comment: @matt In iOS 11 & 12, I could hide the search bar by scrolling the table view upwards. The search bar would 'hide' back into the navigation bar even when there are only few cells in the table view. This doesn't seem to be the case for iOS 13; I can't hide the search bar when the cells do not entirely fill the screen.

Comment: There is an appearance bug with the search controller on iOS13 that I could only work around by setting `searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation` to true. It was not what I wanted but it did work. Not sure if it’s been fixed in the recent patch.

Comment: In iOS13.2.3 the appearance bug with the search controller is still there. (i.e. using a UITableViewController and setting both, `hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling`and `hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation`to `true`.). The searchBar does not disappear when scrolling down...