# iOS 13 - Search Bar not hidden on view display

Tags: uisearchbar, ios13, uisearchcontroller, searchbar

I am in the process of moving apps to iOS 13.  I have many table view controllers in my app, and most have Search Controllers defined.  When I run the apps in iOS 12, when the table view controllers are first displayed, the search bars are hidden, and only appear when I scroll down.

When I run the same apps on iOS 13, the search bars are displayed by default now.  This seems to be the new default behaviour.

Can anyone confirm if this is the new default behaviour?

Can anyone tell me how to get the old default behaviour when running on iOS 13?

I have reviewed many example apps, etc, and cannot restore the old behaviour when the apps are running in iOS 13.

Thx

Comment: Exactly what I am suffering from: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58780350

Comment: In iOS13.2.3 the appearance bug with the search controller is still there. (i.e. using a UITableViewController and setting both, `hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling`and `hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation`to `true`.). The searchBar does not disappear when scrolling down...